# Create a current session variable not working

Tags: php, sql

I have a table and it has more columns:

```
id | username | picture
```

Picture is varchar type and it keeps the path of user  picture
username is varchar and is unique

```
 <?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["logIn"])) {
    $connection = new mysqli(...);

    $email = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $password = sha1($connection->real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));
    $data = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
        $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = 1;
        $picture = $connection->query("SELECT picture FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
        $_SESSION["picture"]=$picture;
        header("Location:../index.php");
        exit();

    }
```

So what I want to do is, create a `$_SESSION["picture"]` variable which will keep the value of the username's picture , i mean the picture of the user that is trying to login now

Comment: You're never calling `fetch_assoc()` to fetch the results of the query.

Comment: @Barmar and what should  i change ?

Comment: `$row = $data->fetch_assoc()`. Any PHP+MySQL tutorial should show the proper way to get data out of a database.

Comment: There's also no need to perform a second query. The picture is in the results of the first query.

Comment: It will be in `$row["picture"]`

Comment: can you please help me ? i just started learning php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call a fetch function to get the data from the table.

```
$data = $connection->query("SELECT picture FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'");
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $data->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = 1;
    $_SESSION["picture"]=$row['picture'];
    header("Location:../index.php");
    exit();
}
```